# Ubercart in-checkout orders from the same user

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

This is related to Drupal 6 & Ubercart...

Is it safe to erase in-checkout orders from a user, except from the last in-checkout order?

The problem is that a user can create multiple orders with "in checkout" status, and it could be confusing for an administrator look multiple orders from the same user. Moreover, the user can only see his last in-checkout order, the rest in-checkout orders are lost... (or not?)

I think a user will never see past in-checkout orders... If a user generates a new order then pasts orders from him should be erased...? Seeing these orders in the history could generate confusion.

Is it safe to delete past in-checkout orders from the same user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be a solution.

After hours of head banging, I had to hack the core ubercart drupal module. I dont know why but the ubercart uc_cart.module unsets the order session everytime the ubercart checkout page is loaded. Hence when the page is loaded or any validation error is there on the checkout page, a new order id is created for preventing the identity theft(which i have no clue what it is).

Coming back to my point. I just commented out the line 142 and 150 in uc_cart.pages.inc of ubercart.
eg:- `unset($_SESSION['cart_order']);`
I m in drupal 6 ubercart

Now since the cart order is not unset hence there are no multiple in checkout status order created. Seems to be working fine for now. I know that hacking core ubercart module is not good, but i couldn't fine any other solution for this. Please do reply if it will cause any future error.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, despite I no longer use Drupal 6 or Ubercart. I'm trying Drupal Commerce in D7, i've heard good things about it.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this solves only one part of duplicated orders. For example, if user goes from checkout review page to the shop to add more products and goes back, another new order is created.